# Assigning a table to a user (oracle, sql plus)

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, privileges

I've just created a user called ugestion (**I'm logged as SYSTEM**). How can I allow him to manage my table tblinstituciones? I just want him to have control over that specific table. Which is the proper command? Nothing seems to work, and I don't want to put "GRANT ALTER ANY TABLE TO ugestion" because I just want him to be able to manage only that specific one. 
**Do I need to give the user some special privilege before executing that command? And, what command should I execute?** I've executed some commands before like, for instance "GRANT ALTER TABLE ON tblinstituciones TO ugestion ; " but it didn't work. I'm starting with **oracle**, sqlplus.

Comment: You can't.  First, you shouldn't be creating objects in the SYSTEM schema.  Second, you can give users the ability to do DML on a table (insert, update, delete) but you can't give users the ability to DDL on a single table.  Realistically, if you want to do that, you should create the table in that user's schema.  You could, I suppose, create a stored procedure that you own that does DDL on the table and grant the user permission to execute that stored procedure but that's a much more complicated approach.

Comment: Thanks but I do not know how to properly do that. Thank you anyway, I'm sure I'll understand this better in the future, and it seems to be very, very useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

When logged in as SYSTEM, issue the following command:

```
DROP TABLE SYSTEM.TBLINSTITUCIONES;
```

That will get rid of the table you created in the SYSTEM schema. As others have mentioned, you should not create tables or other objects in the SYSTEM or SYS schemas.

Next:

Log off of the SYSTEM account.

Next:

Log in as the UGESTION user.

Next:

```
CREATE TABLE UGESTION.TBLINSTITUCIONES
  (put all your field definitions here);
```

replacing "put all your field definitions here" with the definitions of whatever fields you need to create in this table. The statement above will not work until you do this.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I've already created the table! I'll have in account not to create tables as SYSTEM from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the table.

Re-create it, but in your CREATE TABLE command, pre-fix the table name with your USER name...a la

```
Create Table Scott.Stackoverflow (
 A Integer,
 B Varchar2(20),
 C Clob);
```

Where SCOTT would be the schema/user you want the table to belong too, and of course substitute the actual DDL with your original.

You could also do...

```
 CREATE TABLE SCOTT.STACKOVERFLOW AS SELECT * FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE;
```

CTAS won't grab things like column comments, constraints, indexes, etc.

Now they OWN the table. They can do anything they want with it. It's theirs. They can drop it. They can alter it. They can insert/update/delete/truncate it. They can grant privs to others.

You shouldn't ever create objects in the SYSTEM schema (OR SYS!) for what it's worth.

Comment: When I execute your command, it says I'm missing left parenthesis. Where should I put a parenthesis? If I type it like this "CREATE TABLE (username.tablename) ;" it gives me error too. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

System user shouldn't be used for any user objects. Please do:

```
create table ugestion.tblinstituciones as select * from system.tblinstituciones;
drop table system.tblinstituciones;
```

This way both table definition and data will be moved (in fact you creating new table with data in new schema) from system to user schema.